# finite cover of clopen sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

**Definition:**

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are two covers of $X.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of  $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper subset of some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ if $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A},$ we write $\mathcal{A} < \mathcal{B}.$

Here is the problem: Let $X$ be a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, and let $\epsilon > 0.$

(a) Show that $X$ has a finite cover $\mathcal{A}$ clopen sets with diameter at most $\epsilon.$

Could anyone help me in the solution, please?

Comment: (1) What can you say about the diameter of an open set and the diameter of its closure? (2) How can you use "totally disconnected" to product clopen sets?

Comment: One way to approach this is by using the fact that if $X$ is compact metric then $X$ is totally disconnected if and only if it is zero-dimensional (in the sense of small inductive dimension). [See wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space). However that might be an overkill.

Comment: $X$ is zero-dimensional and so has covering dimension $0$ too. Now it follows by definition.

Comment: @freakish This lemma in turn implies that $X$ is zero-dimensional, so I'm not sure it's overkill. We need components= quasicomponents.

Comment: @TokenToucan I know that the diameter of  an open ball is $\leq 2r $ and in $\mathbb{R^n}$ it is equal to $2r. $

Comment: I know nothing about zero-dimensional @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @freakish I know nothing about zero-dimensional

Comment: @Happy you only need to know all balls contain clopen sets.