# finite cover of clopen sets with diameter at most $\epsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Here is the problem:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, and let $\epsilon > 0.$

(a) Show that $X$ has a finite cover $\mathcal{A}$ clopen sets with diameter at most $\epsilon.$

**My trial.**

With the help of many people here on this site I was able to prove that:

If $X$ is a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, then for each $r > 0$ and each $x \in X,$ there is a clopen set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \subseteq B_{r}(x).$

I feel like this may help me in the proof of the first question but I do not know how, could anyone clarify this for me, please?

Also, I received hints here   [finite cover of clopen sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607330/finite-cover-of-clopen-sets?noredirect=1#comment7415918_3607330) but still, I am unable to write the solution thoroughly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You’re practically done. For each $x\in X$ you have a clopen $U_x$ such that $x\in U_x\subseteq B_{\epsilon/2}(x)$. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_x:x\in X\}$; this is an open cover of $X$. And $X$ is compact, so …

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what about the" diameter at most $\epsilon $ " part?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I, with the help of many of the people here, knew the proof that every open ball has diameter $\leq 2r$ does this help in the remaining part?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what you need: $B_{\epsilon/2}(x)$ has diameter at most $2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon$.

Comment: I knew the proof for equality in case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but in any other metric space its $\leq  2r.$ I think the problem here does not require equality .... am I correct? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You are correct: you just need sets with diameter **at most** $\epsilon$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why you took the radius of the open ball $B_{\epsilon / 2}(x)$ to be $\epsilon / 2$ and not $ \epsilon $ only?

Comment: Because I wanted its **diameter** to be at most $\epsilon$. Had I taken its radius to be $\epsilon$, its diameter could have been as much as $2\epsilon$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott does the question means every clopen set in the finite cover has a diameter at most  $\epsilon$ or the whole finite cover has diameter at most $\epsilon$? I think if it is the latter then we should divide by $2n$ instead of $2$ only assuming that the number of clopen sets in the finite cover is $n$ .... am I correct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you please look at this question for me (if you have time ) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607855/showing-that-mathcala-refines-mathcalb-and-distinct-numbers-of-mathc ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you have an answer for my comment just before the last one?

Comment: It means that each of the clopen sets has diameter at most $\epsilon$.